# Clipped scope's bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, bounding-box, path-clipping

In the following example, I `\clip` out a 3x3 rectangle of an image. I'd expect the resulting `scope` to have a bounding box of 3x3, so the two text `node`s should line up with the extent of the clipped picture. Instead, the `(0,0)` and `(3,3)` labels show up where I would expect them if I *didn't* clip the image.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
  \clip (9, 5) rectangle ++ (-3,-3);
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image.jpg}};
\end{scope}

\draw (0,0) node{(0,0)};
\draw (3,3) node{(3,3)};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I clip the `scope` so that its bounding box goes from `(0,0)` to `(3,3)` while keeping the same contents as currently? I.e. I'd like this:

[image]

(Note that this is a simplified example. In my real use case, there is a lot of drawing happening (and no images involved) in the `scope`, so this has nothing to do with using an image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @SebGlav, it seems that you are looking for a combination of two commands `clip` (which defines which part of the image is visible) and `shift` (which changes the origin).

To simplify this double command, you can define a new `clip and shift` style that does the job.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  % usage in scope style: clip and shift={path}
  clip and shift/.code = {
    \clip #1 (current path bounding box.south west)
      coordinate (clip and shift origin);
  },
  clip and shift/.append style = {shift={(clip and shift origin)}}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \fill[red] (9,5) circle(3pt) node[above right]{(9,5)};
    \fill[red] (7,2) circle(3pt) node[below left]{(7,2)};

    \begin{scope}[clip and shift={(9,5) rectangle +(-2,-3)}]
      \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image.jpg}};

      \fill[blue] (0,0) circle(3pt) node[above right]{(0,0)};
      \fill[blue] (2,3) circle(3pt) node[below left]{(2,3)};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** The code was adapted to fit @cactus requests from comments.

[image]

Comment: Can you show how that generalizes to non-rectangular clips? I wanted to make my question simple so I used a rectangle, but my real use case is a complicated clipping path.

Comment: @Cactus It is not obvious what you want to do with "complicated" path : where the origin should be moved ? May be you can ask another question with MWE that describes exactly what you want. In any case you can use inside `\clip` any kind of paths.

Comment: I'd like the origin to be in the leftmost-bottommost point of the bounding box of the clipping path.

Comment: @Cactus now it works with general path as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would find `use as bounding box` syntax interesting. And then use a scope with shifting the coordinate system.

[image: use as bounding box]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
        \clip (6,2) rectangle (9,5);
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0)
            {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image.jpg}};
        \useasboundingbox (6,2) rectangle (9,5);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=2cm]
            \draw[red] (0,0) grid (3,3);
            \path (0,0) node{(0,0)};
            \path (3,3) node{(3,3)};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

If you want to use your clip as bounding box (and not type it once more), you can define your clip like a reusable path:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\clipbox{(6,2) rectangle (9,5)} % <--- Define here
        \begin{scope}
        \clip \clipbox; % <--- Use here
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0)
            {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image.jpg}};
        \useasboundingbox \clipbox; % <--- And use there
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=2cm]
            \draw[red] (0,0) grid (3,3);
            \path (0,0) node{(0,0)};
            \path (3,3) node{(3,3)};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This... is horrible. Is there a way to 1. use the clip as the bounding box (in my real use case, the clip path is quite complicated) and 2. do the shift to origin automatically based on the bounding box?

Comment: You may want to provide something closer to your real needs, so that someone could give you what you really want.

Comment: I edited my post to avoid retyping the scope, even if it answered the question in the first place.